# Need efficient way to do simple computation on 200million row database (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, database, performance

I am requesting a PHP solution for the following problem:

I have a ~15 tables in a database, each with 10-50 million rows, all summing up to 200 million rows, with columns userID, B, C, D.

I have 9 other tables with columns userID, fbID. Each table has ~2 million rows. There is a one to one mapping from userID to fbID.

My goal is to output a file of these 200 million rows with columns fbID, B, C, D.

In order to do this, I must search through all the 9 tables that contain columns userID and fbID because the userID may be found in one table, but not the others. I can stop as soon as I find the userID in any one of these tables. This part I am using SQL along with PHP. The SQL query includes LIMIT 1 so I only return 1 row whenever I find the userID, as these tables can contain multiple rows with the same userID.

This algorithm unfortunately takes ~60s/1k rows, which will take me ~130 days to finish.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I'm not an expert on how database computation times work, but some ideas I've thought of:

-query through all 9 tables and make a lookup table with userID keys and fBID values.

-create a new table inside the database using these 9 tables with one row per userID, along with the corresponding FBID and search through this one.

Here's more specific info on the tables:

**Tables summing up to 200 million rows (each one looks like this):**

```
Column         Type        Null      Default 

dtLogTime      datetime    Yes       NULL 

iUin           int(10)     No         

B              int(10)     No

C              int(10)     No

D              int(10)     No
```

Indexes:

```
Keyname   Type  Unique Packed Column    Cardinality Collation Null Comment 

dtLogTime BTREE No     No     dtLogTime 323542      A         YES  

iUin      BTREE No     No     iUin      323542      A
```

**One of the 9 other tables:**

```
Column     Type        Null     Default     Comments 

dtLogTime  datetime    Yes      NULL   

iUin       int(10)     No         

vFBID      varchar(48) No
```

Indexes:

```
Keyname   Type  Unique Packed Column    Cardinality Collation Null Comment 

dtLogTime BTREE No     No     dtLogTime 2179789     A         YES  

iUin      BTREE No     No     iUin      2179789     A
```

**Sample Code I've tried:**

```
// returns FBID of iuin
function getFBID($iuin){

$query = sprintf("SELECT vFBID FROM `tbReg` WHERE iuin = " . $iuin . " LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  return $row['vFBID'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);

$query = sprintf("SELECT vFBID FROM `tbOnline` WHERE iuin = " . $iuin . " LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  return $row['vFBID'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);

$query = sprintf("SELECT vFBID FROM `tbConsumeFBC` WHERE iuin = " . $iuin . " LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  return $row['vFBID'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);

$query = sprintf("SELECT vFBID FROM `tbFeed` WHERE iuin = " . $iuin . " LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   return $row['vFBID'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);

$query = sprintf("SELECT vFBID FROM `tbInvite` WHERE iuin = " . $iuin . " LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   return $row['vFBID'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);  

$query = sprintf("SELECT vFBID FROM `tbFreeGift` WHERE iuin = " . $iuin . " LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   return $row['vFBID'];
}
mysql_free_result($result); 

$query = sprintf("SELECT vFBID FROM `tbUninstall` WHERE iuin = " . $iuin . " LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   return $row['vFBID'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);  

$query = sprintf("SELECT vFBID FROM `tbDownload` WHERE iuin = " . $iuin . " LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   return $row['vFBID'];
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT vFBID FROM `tbIUserSource` WHERE iuin = " . $iuin . " LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   return $row['vFBID'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
}

fwrite($handle, '"Time","FBID","Action","ActionID"' . "\n");

$query = sprintf("SELECT count(dtLogTime) AS length
                  FROM `tbActionWeeding`");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$length = ceil($row['length'] * 0.0001);
$start = 0;
$i = 0;
while($i++ < 10000)
   $query = sprintf("SELECT dtLogTime, iuin, iWeedID
                     FROM `tbActionWeeding`
                     LIMIT " . $start . "," . $length);
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   if (!$result) {
      $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
      $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query . "\n";
      die($message);
   }
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      fwrite($handle, '"' . $row['dtLogTime'] . '","' . getFBID($row['iuin']) .
                   '","0","' . $row['iWeedID'] . "\"\n");
   mysql_free_result($result);
   $start += $length;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a `JOIN` would help you here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: Is this algorithm part of a larger normalization effort? If not, may I suggest that you consider the benefits of one?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention these other 9 tables each have ~2 million rows, and I recall I had trouble joining tables from a previous project.

Comment: What database are you using? You might be better off to use a command line utility like sqlplus or mysql. Also, if performance is an issue on joining, consider indexing the join columns.

Comment: PLease clarify: are you searching for values of `userID` column from '200 million rows table' in `fbID` column of these 9 smaller tables? Is your goal to return only these rows from the large table, that has matching rows in any of 9 smaller tables?

Comment: @Mchl
I want to return all rows from the '200 million rows table' regardless of if there's a matching userID in the '9 smaller tables' or not. Indeed I'm searching the value of userID in the '9 smaller tables', and returning the corresponding fbID once found

Comment: Can you tell us the table structures (in MySQL, `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable1` and a sample query?  Do you have indexes on the columns you're searching on?

Comment: @Mark: I get it now. Misread your question.

Comment: please provide some sample schema/data for the database. Also, you specify you wish to do this in PHP but are you open to a database SQL solution if it is more efficient?

Comment: Can you also specify what you've already tried?  Some example code (in the question) goes a long way towards illustrating a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I've addressed all the comments in the opening question since I don't know how to format my comments

Comment: @Bueller, yes modifying the database is also a feasible solution, but I am only allowed to create new tables and not touch any of the existing tables

Answer (score 5):

> > I have 9 other tables with columns userID, fbID

and

> > these other 9 tables each have ~2 million rows

The inefficiency of this data structure cannot easily be surmounted using clever code alone. Because you are required to process huge amounts of redundant data, the most efficient algorithm will run slowly against this architecture.

What you need is [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You should alter the structure of your tables to remove redundant data. This will eliminate the need to search nine separate tables 200 million times, providing a considerable improvement in efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Now this could work, although just like others said in comments, it would be good to know if you have proper indexes.

```
SELECT
  u.fbID, t.B, t.C, t.d
FROM
  veryLargeTable AS t
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT userId, fbID FROM
    smallerTable1 
  UNION SELECT userId, fbID FROM
    smallerTable2 
  ...
  UNION SELECT userId, fbID FROM
    smallerTable9 
) AS u USING (userId)
```

You might want to run it on smaller dataset first to see how it performs.

Comment: hey sorry, i was trying to simplify the problem, but the very large table is actually ~15 tables each ranging from 10-50 million rows, and they sum up to ~200 million rows. Do you think this solution will still work?

Comment: Ugh... well yeah... you did simplify it a little... You could however run either 15 queries like this and merge results, or use UNION to maerge these 15 tables just like I did with 9 tables above. This will most certainly be slow...

Answer (score 0):

Just understand that the most efficient method possible may still take some time just because of the row count.

The first real problem is that you need this to be in PHP.  How absolute is that?  If it is at all possible to work on the database itself, you want to do this:

```
-- 
-- Index all 9 tables on userid,fbId

select UserId,fbId
  into WorkingTable_UserId_to_fbId
  from table1Of9
union all
select UserId,fbId
  from table_2_of_9
--
-- repeat the UNION all clause up to:
UNION ALL
select UserId,fbId
  from table_9_of_9
GROUP BY 1,2

-- Index resulting table on userId,fbId
```

This gives you a working table that makes the basic query this:

```
select Linker.Fbid,main.b,main.c.,main.d
  from mainTable main
  JOIN WorkingTable_UserId_to_FbId linker on main.userId = linker.userId
```

If it is absolutely not possible to create that table, then you must take the same code and insert it into the query above, and it just ain't gonna go that fast.  It would be:

```
select Linker.Fbid,main.b,main.c.,main.d
  from mainTable main
  JOIN (  select UserId,fbId
           from table1Of9
          union all
         select UserId,fbId
           from table_2_of_9
         -- etc, etc.

       ) Linker on main.userId = linker.userId
```

However, this will likely stall out as the server tries to gather 200 million rows to get ready to return to PHP.  So you need to break it into chunks, fetching perhaps 10000 rows at a shot.  It may be tempting to add OFFSET...LIMIT to the above query, but that still puts a heavy load on the server.  it is better to handle that in PHP, something like:

```
# Very sloppy code off the top of my head,
# modify this loop based on what you know of the
# userId values
$id = 1;
while($id <= 200000000) {
    $topId = $id + 9999;
    $sql="select Linker.Fbid,main.b,main.c.,main.d
            from mainTable main
            JOIN WorkingTable_UserId_to_FbId linker on main.userId = linker.userId
           WHERE main.userId between $id and $topId";

    # Note: don't freak out about SQL injection in the above code,
    #       you are hardcoding the values of ID, not getting them from a user

    #
    # Execute query, retrieve rows, output
    # then up the counter:
    $id+=1000;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm able to create that table within the database. Could you comment on the speed of this solution? Is there a high chance that this will reduce the speed significantly once I make this table?

Comment: The table will speed it up, especially after the index is added.  The reason is that you are really now using the index instead of the table itself, and since the index contains both values, once it has found the UserId, the fbId is stored right with it.  Also, since you mention there are dupes, this table has eliminated them and is more efficient.